How to wait until multiprocessing.connection.Client is available in python?
I have a process.py script:
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener

with Listener(('localhost', 6000)) as listener:
    with listener.accept() as connection:
        message = connection.recv()
        # [...]
        connection.send(message)

I launch this script in a thread (to avoid blocking the main thread) with:
import threading, subprocess
threading.Thread(target=lambda: subprocess.run(['python', 'process.py'])).start()


But sometimes I want to wait (block the main thread) until my process has launched.
Here is what I do:
from multiprocessing.connection import Client

nAttempts = 0
while True:
    try:
        with Client(('localhost', 6000)) as connection:
            connection.send(nAttempts)
            message = connection.recv()
            # [...]
            break
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        nAttempts += 1
        pass

Is there a better approach?
The program tries ~282 connections before being able to connect, can it be a problem?

Are you able to modify process.py?

Yes, but I don't see how it could help?

@arthur.sw often when people are in a position where they cannot modify an existing script for various reasons, they will run it as a subprocess. If you have full control of the script, it is probably better to create a function which you  pass to a multiprocessing.Process. You can then also pass something like a multiprocessing.Event to signal to the main process when the Listener is ready.

Good point. The reason I use subprocess.run() is to run a python script in another environment. More precisely, I do something like subprocess.run(['conda activate myenv && python process.py'.split(' ')]).

So I don't think I can use multiprocessing directly, since it will necessarily run in the same python env, unless I missed something.

First, modify process.py so that you can import what you need:
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener

def listen(listening_event=None):
    with Listener(('localhost', 6000)) as listener:
        if listening_event:
            listening_event.set()  # Signal that we are now listening
    
        with listener.accept() as connection:
            message = connection.recv()
            # [...]
            connection.send(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listen()

Then you main script would be:
import threading

from process import listen

listening_event = threading.Event()
t = threading.Thread(target=listen, args=(listening_event,))
t.start()
listening_event.wait()  # Wait for this notification
...
t.join()  #  Wait for thread to terminate (if it ever does)

If you need to use multiprocessing, then:
import multiprocessing

from process import listen

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listening_event = multiprocessing.Event()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=listen, args=(listening_event,))
    p.start()
    listening_event.wait()  # Wait for this notification
    ...
    p.join()  #  Wait for process to terminate (if it ever does)

Update
Based on your comment, we can determine that the process.py listener is ready for accepting connection in the following way:
The Main Script
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener, Client
from threading import Thread
import subprocess

def run_process():
    subprocess.run('conda activate myenv && python process.py', shell=True)

def wait_for_listener_ready():
    with Listener(('localhost', 6001), backlog=5) as listener:
        process_thread = Thread(target=run_process)
        process_thread.start()
        with listener.accept() as connection:
            connection.recv()
            connection.send('Okay')
    return process_thread

# Wait process.py to be ready:
process_thread = wait_for_listener_ready()

...

process_thread.join()

Here the main script is starting its own listener on an agreed-up port (assumed to be 6001). The process.py script will send a message to our listener when it is ready to accept connections:
process.py
from multiprocessing.connection import Listener, Client

with Listener(('localhost', 6000), backlog=5) as listener:
    with Client(('localhost', 6001)) as starter_connection:
        starter_connection.send('Hello')
        starter_connection.recv()

    with listener.accept() as connection:
        message = connection.recv()
        connection.send(message.upper())


Thanks! Unfortunately, I use subprocess.run() is to run a python script in another environment. More precisely, I do something like subprocess.run(['conda activate myenv && python process.py'.split(' ')]). So I don't think I can use threading.Event ; or can I?

See my update that should work for you.

Using the problem as the solution... smart :) Compared to my solution, this also eliminates external dependencies and the possibility of leaking objects into the windows mutex namespace or /shm namespace. Sockets are at least closed when a process exits, whereas named objects may live until reboot.

First of all, I think it is not necessarily wrong to do what you are currently doing. I would put a timeout on it or a maximum number of retries, but that applies to any solution really..
Named IPC constructs from the operating system are generally my solution for synchronization between scripts which must be in different environments. On windows you can use pywin32 to create a named mutex (or semaphore, event, etc...), and on most others you can use posix-ipc
Windows:
import win32event
from pywintypes import HANDLE

#create a named event from main script
def createEvent(name: str) -> HANDLE:
    return win32event.CreateEvent(None, True, False, name)

#open a named event from listener
def openEvent(name: str) -> HANDLE:
    return win32event.OpenEvent(win32event.EVENT_ALL_ACCESS, True, name)

#signal the event from the listener
def signalEvent(event: HANDLE):
    win32event.SetEvent(event)

#await the event from the main script
def awaitEvent(event: HANDLE, timeout_ms: int = -1):
    win32event.WaitForSingleObject(event, timeout_ms)

POSIX:
import posix_ipc

#create a named semaphore from main script
def createSemaphore(name: str) -> HANDLE:  # name must be filesystem-valid name starting with "/"
    return posix_ipc.Semaphore(name, posix_ipc.O_CREX, 0)

#open a named semaphore from listener
def openSemaphore(name: str) -> HANDLE:
    return posix_ipc.Semaphore(name, 0)

#signal the semaphore from the listener
def signalSemaphore(semaphore: posix_ipc.Semaphore):
    semaphore.release()

#await the semaphore from the main script
def awaitSemaphore(semaphore: posix_ipc.Semaphore, timeout: float|None = None):
    if timeout and not posix_ipc.SEMAPHORE_TIMEOUT_SUPPORTED:
        raise NotImplementedError("platform does not support sem_timedwait() (MacOS?)")
    semaphore.acquire(timeout)
    semaphore.unlink() #when you're done with it

I put these into functions named for what they're intending to do, but they're all pretty much one-liners, and don't actually need to be in functions of their own...
